# How get return of value from the callback function of loadJSON in P5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Generally I have this code with Javascript and P5.js:

Just for get data from url and work with it with other function even don't need to reload it many times.

```js
function setup() {
  var main = document.getElementById('main');
  var start = document.createElement('button');
  main.appendChild(start);
  start.setAttribute('onclick', 'go()');
  // consideration of create TextNode of start button
}

function go() {
  loadJSON('url', treatData);
}

function treatData(data) {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(data);

  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  //consideration of append btn var and create TextNode of it

  btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'get()');

  return arr;
}

function get() {
 // when i call treateData() here it is not work. 
  // so how get arr here;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to call the `treatData()` function from anywhere other than using it as a callback to the `loadJSON()` function.

If you want to access the data that gets loaded, you could store it in a variable. Something like this:

```
var arr;

function go() {
  loadJSON('url', treatData);
}

function treatData(data) {
  arr = data;
}

function get() {
  console.log(arr);
}
```